# Adding data to MySQL with Fatal Error - Magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento, fatal-error

I have magento 1.7.0.2 and now i try to add some data to the database.
But i get an error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: this in /var/www/vhosts/xxx/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php on line 10 Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup' not found in /var/www/vhosts/xxx/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php on line 3
```

Here is the part of the php file which tries to add some data to the database:

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();

/**
 * Adding Different Attributes
 */

// adding attribute group
$setup->addAttributeGroup('catalog_product', 'Default', 'Video', 1000);

$setup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'videobox', array(
    'group'         => 'Video',
    'input'         => 'textarea',
    'type'          => 'text',
    'label'         => 'Youtube video url',
    'backend'       => '',
    'visible'       => 1,
    'required'      => 0,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'searchable' => 0,
    'filterable' => 0,
    'comparable'    => 0,
    'visible_on_front' => 1,
    'visible_in_advanced_search'  => 0,
    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => 0,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
));
```

How can this be fixed?
Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
The files works.
I have added a extra piece of code to see if it works:

```
<?php

require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app(); // Change default to whatever store you want to run

echo "it's worked!";

?>
```

The error has moved a line down now.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function startSetup() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/xxx/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php on line 4
```

Comment: Is this the start of the file?

Comment: yes, it is. Line 3 is `$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

`$setup = Mage::getModel("eav/entity_setup", "core_setup");`

instead of calling directly. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

A problem might be class is not found in mage directory just carefully include mage.php
will sure solve your issue.

```
$mageFilename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/magento/app/Mage.php';
```

Use this. It worked for me.

`DOCUMENT_ROOT` is a server variable that represents the base directory that your code is located within.

Comment: pls check with other function is it working ? like models/ or layout function

Comment: Hi, can you specify a line to me? I am not that into this kind of code. (i can read it, but not programm it)

Comment: http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/run-magento-code-externally/ just refer this

Comment: This worked a bit. Now my error has moved to `Fatal error: Call to a member function startSetup() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/xxx/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php on line 4`

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/catalog/adding_a_new_attribute or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340296/magento-module-installator check